# Can I use both PHP and JavaScript Facebook APIs?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I want to provide logging with facebook on my webpage. How can I use both APIs to get some facebook user info using PHP in one place and JS in other place? 
This is link to offical php sdk example usage (together with JS sdk):

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php

What i want to do is to use somewhere in that file this code for example:

```
FB.api("/me", function (response) {
      alert('Name is ' + response.name);
});
```

or other JS sdk code to get some user info.

I always have a problem that when I use one type of logging in (PHP or JS) I can use only one kind of api to call for info. I don't know how to provide logging in which will make available both APIs. Someone knows how to do it? Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried just getting it with PHP and then feeding it to your JavaScript when the pages are created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just using the php sdk at the same time still can you js api, in your script, just add this in your html body ,

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   FB.init({
     appId  : '<?=$yourappid?>',
     status : true, 
     cookie : true, 
     xfbml  : true  
   });
 </script>
```

and try call call this

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
FB.api("/me", function (response) {
          alert('Name is ' + response.name);
    });
</script>
```

anyone pls correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: That's it! I thought i tried every combination of those APIs. But this one really works!